# EXC_BAD_ACCESS On reading and writing to plist files

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm getting tonnes of EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors related to the following two functions for reading and writing to plist files. I think its memory related. Any suggestions?

```
+(NSString *) getSettingString: (NSString *)key defaultValue:(NSString *)defValue
{
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"FSSettings_v3.plist"];
    [pathArray release];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
    if (fileExists == YES) {
        NSMutableDictionary* plistDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSString *value =  [plistDictionary objectForKey:key];
        return value;
    } else {
        [self setSettingString:key value:defValue];
        return defValue;
    }

}

+(void) setSettingString: (NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value
{
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"FSSettings_v3.plist"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
    if (fileExists == YES) {
        NSMutableDictionary* plistDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [plistDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
        [plistDictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        [plistDictionary release];
    } else {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setObject:value forKey:key];
        [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        [dict release];
    }
    [pathArray release];
}
```

Comment: Start with debug configuration and it will stop right away at the correct line when it crashes. This will help you narrow down why it crashes and what variable is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't release `pathArray` in the first method:

```
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"FSSettings_v3.plist"];
[pathArray release];
```

`NSSearchNSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns an autoreleased object.
Always do "Build&Analyze" in the XCode. It will tell you many retain/release problems.

That said, don't re-invent the wheel. You can just use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Your code becomes four lines:

```
+(NSString *) settingString: (NSString *)key defaultValue:(NSString *)defValue
{
       NSString*v=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:key];
       if(v){
             return v;
       }else{
             return defValue;
       }
}

+(void) setSettingString: (NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value
{
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:key]
}
```

I would register the default to the `NSUserDefaults` using [`registerDefaults:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:), instead of supplying it to `-getSettingString`.

Finally, you shouldn't put `get` in the name of the getter. That's against the custom of Objective-C.
In Objective-C, `get` is typically used only when the result is returned through a pointer passed in as the argument of the method, as in [`-[NSData getBytes:length:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/getBytes:length:).